# Configuration for list of objects

Tags: java, quarkus

Using Quarkus configuration system, what would be the best way to inject a list of objects in my application ?

In my case I want to configure a list of servers and their types. Using yaml configs that would be :

```
app.servers
  - uri: host1
    type: type1
  - uri: host2
    type: type2
```

I can only find solution for array of primitive types but is it possible for custom class ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the question was asked [quarkus begun supporting yaml configuration](https://quarkus.io/guides/config#yaml) file so the easiest way to configure a list of objects would be through a .yaml config file

For that just add the following dependency :

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
    <artifactId>quarkus-config-yaml</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

If you still need to have it as a .properties file then what I ended up doing (because yaml was not supported yet) was to implement a [custom property converter](https://quarkus.io/guides/config#custom-configuration-sources).

Answer (score 0):

I am facing with the same issue, unfortunately, [custom property converter](https://quarkus.io/guides/config#custom-configuration-sources) is still immature, it will concatenate the yaml object to one string like this:

```
uri=host1type=type1
```

You have to split it programmatically and create your dto.

This is really ugly...